# how to add Jython with a Gradle plugin?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, classpath, jython

How do I use the [Jython plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.rzabini.gradle-jython) to download the dependencies and add them to the classpath with Gradle?

The repositories task has:

```
maven{url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
```

and the dependencies task has:

```
compile "gradle.plugin.com.github.rzabini:gradle-jython:1.0.2"
```

Does that pull-in Jython itself?  I don't see that it does, because after deleting `~/gradle/cache/` gradle redownloads the plugin but I don't see JAR's:

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$ gradle clean run
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/github/rzabini/gradle-jython/1.0.2/gradle-jython-1.0.2.pom
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/2.0.0/gradle-download-task-2.0.0.pom
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/github/rzabini/gradle-jython/1.0.2/gradle-jython-1.0.2.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/2.0.0/gradle-download-task-2.0.0.jar
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:runJan 16, 2017 5:25:17 AM net.bounceme.dur.nfl.Run main
INFO: hello nfl
Jan 16, 2017 5:25:17 AM net.bounceme.dur.nfl.Run init
INFO: will now invoke jython
Jan 16, 2017 5:25:17 AM net.bounceme.dur.nfl.JythonBean <init>
INFO: java bean for now..
Jan 16, 2017 5:25:17 AM net.bounceme.dur.nfl.JythonBean createInterpreter
INFO: jython to follow


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.412 secs
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$
```

However, cannot instantiate a [Jython Interpreter](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/22390-executing-jython-function-java) after adding that line:

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$ gradle run
:compileJava/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/nfl/src/main/java/net/bounceme/dur/nfl/JythonBean.java:15: error: package org.python.util does not exist
        org.python.util.PythonInterpreter interp = new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter();
                       ^
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/nfl/src/main/java/net/bounceme/dur/nfl/JythonBean.java:15: error: package org.python.util does not exist
        org.python.util.PythonInterpreter interp = new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter();
                                                                      ^
2 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.816 secs
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/nfl$
```

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nfl;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JythonBean {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JythonBean.class.getName());

    public JythonBean() {
        log.info("java bean for now..");
    }

    public void createInterpreter() {
        log.info("jython to follow");
        org.python.util.PythonInterpreter interp = new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter();
        //   interp.execfile("script1.py");

    }

}
```

The PythonInterpreter line was commented out for the first gradle run so that it would be successful.  I've also tried this from Netbeans, clean and build, same result.

build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'application'

String mavenGroupId = 'thufir'
String mavenVersion = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'


// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.


mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.nfl.Run'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'net.bounceme.dur.nfl.Run'
}

repositories {
 //   mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
maven{
url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
}

dependencies {
    //TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    //You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
//    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
//  classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.rzabini:gradle-jython:1.0.2"
    compile "gradle.plugin.com.github.rzabini:gradle-jython:1.0.2"
}






    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
         //   java.srcDirs = ['src']
//            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
  //          aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
    //        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
      //      res.srcDirs = ['res']
        //    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
```

Comment: In December 2015 Jim Baker, one of the main geniuses behind Jython, said (http://bugs.jython.org/msg10557) that Gradle functionality for Jython was a big priority for 2.7.2.  I just opened an Issue (https://github.com/rzabini/gradle-jython/issues/10#issuecomment-358433893) with rzabini, author of the Gradle Jython plugin you reference, and as I suspected he only created this plugin for a specific Python purpose and not for full Jython use with Gradle.  It's sometimes difficult to know what's happening with the Jython project...